# Logstash can't send logs to mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, logstash

I'm trying to save the logs to my local mongoDB with logstash. this is my configuration in logstash:

```
input {
  tcp { 
    port => 5001
    codec => "json_lines"
  }
}

output {
  file {
    path => "/var/log/some.log"
  }

  mongodb {
    id => "logstash-mongo"
    collection => "logs"
    database => "somelogs"
    uri => "mongodb://my-user:my-password@127.0.0.1:27017/somelogs"
    codec => "json"
  }

  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

For output to file its actually works, but not for output to mongoDB. I setup the mongoDB using authentication. I created both admin and basic user for read and write to the specific db. I tried to run logstash but its give me this:

```
2021-10-29T06:37:51,798][WARN ][logstash.outputs.mongodb ][main][logstash-mongo] Failed to send event to MongoDB, retrying in 3 seconds {:event=>#<LogStash::Event:0x2f0b40c8>, :except
ion=>#<Mongo::Auth::Unauthorized: User my-user is not authorized to access somelogs.>}
[2021-10-29T06:37:54,887][WARN ][logstash.outputs.mongodb ][main][logstash-mongo] Failed to send event to MongoDB, retrying in 3 seconds {:event=>#<LogStash::Event:0x2f0b40c8>, :except
ion=>#<Mongo::Error::OperationFailure: command insert requires authentication (13)>}
```

I'm using both user to access the mongoDB but its still give me this output. Any suggestion what I have to do with this issue? many thanks

NOTE: I've done install output plugins for mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake, the uri must be

> uri => "mongodb://my-user:my-password@127.0.0.1:27017

instead of

> uri => "mongodb://my-user:my-password@127.0.0.1:27017/somelogs

The logstash running well now